# Extracting snmpdump values (with an exact MIB) from a shell script

Tags: bash

I have a a some SNMP dump:

```
  1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2.0|5|1.3.6.1.4.1.9.1.1178
  1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0|7|1881685367
  1.3.6.1.2.1.1.4.0|6|""
  1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0|6|"hgfdhg-4365.gfhfg.dfg.com"
  1.3.6.1.2.1.1.6.0|6|""
  1.3.6.1.2.1.1.7.0|2|6
  1.3.6.1.2.1.1.8.0|7|0
  1.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.2.1|5|1.3.6.1.4.1.9.7.129
  1.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.2.2|5|1.3.6.1.4.1.9.7.115
```

And need to grep all data in first string after 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2.0|5|, but not include this start of the string in grep itself. So, I must receive 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.1.1178 in grep. I've tried to use regex:

```
  \b1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2.0\|5\|\s*([^\n\r]*)
```

But without any success. If a regular expression, or `grep`, is in fact the right tool, can you help me find the right regex? Otherwise, what tools should I consider instead?

Comment: Use awk with field separator as the pipe symbol and print out the third field then pipe the result to grep.

Comment: `\s` and `\b` are PCRE extensions. They aren't available in BRE (used by `grep` by default) or ERE (used with `egrep` or `grep -E`).

Comment: BTW, is there a reason you're using grep rather than awk or sed for this job?

Comment: Hi, @CharlesDuffy ! The reason is that I'm new in bash, and don't know sed and awk yet.

Comment: I've generalized the question to no longer be specific to a single tool. The answer you already have is a good one, and there's no reason not to have it be accepted, but the form in which the question was asked was preventing other potentially-useful answers from being strictly applicable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU `grep` +PCRE support, you can use `Perl`'s `\K` flag to discard part of the matched string :

```
grep -Po "1\.3\.6\.1\.2\.1\.1\.2\.0\|5\|\K.*"
```

`-P` enables `Perl`'s regex mode and `-o` switches output to matched parts rather than whole lines.

I had to escape the characters that have special meaning in Perl regexs, but this can be avoided as [123](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4923629/123) suggests, by enclosing the characters to interpret literally between `\Q` and `\E`  :

```
grep -Po "\Q1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2.0|5|\E\K.*"
```

---

I would usually solve this with `sed` as follows :

```
sed -n 's/1\.3\.6\.1\.2\.1\.1\.2\.0|5|\(.*\)/\1/p'
```

The `-n` flag disables implicit output and the search and replace command will remove the searched prefix from the line, leaving the relevant part to be printed.

The characters that have special meaning in GNU Basic Regular Expressions (BRE) must be escaped, which in this case is only `.`. Also note that the grouping tokens are `\(` and `\)` rather than the usual `(` and `)`.

Comment: Only GNU grep, and only builds of GNU grep with optional PCRE support compiled in.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks, I mentioned that and added a `sed` alternative that I believe to be portable

Comment: As you are using the `P` flag you may as well disable special characters using \Q and \E. Saves you escaping everything. `grep -Po "\Q1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2.0|5|\E\K.*"`

Comment: @123 Thanks, I've edited my answer to include your suggestion.

Comment: @123 and Aaron - Thanks for your answers and suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

An alternate way to do this is in native shell, without any regexes at all. Consider:

```
prefix='1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2.0|5|'
while read -r line; do
  [[ $line = "$prefix"* ]] && printf '%s\n' "${line#$prefix}"
done
```

If your original string is piped into the `while read` loop, the output is precisely `1.3.6.1.4.1.9.1.1178`.